# combobox with different datacontext for ItemsSource and SelectedItem

Tags: silverlight, combobox, datacontext, selecteditem, itemssource

So i have a combobox as the CellEditingTemplate of a datagrid and selected item is bound to the datacontext of that row as expected, but i need the combobox to be populated from a ObservableCollection outside of the context of the datagrid from the ViewModel.

How could i acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In this case the most likely scenario is to specify a `Source` for your binding on the `ComboBox`.

```
<Grid.Resources>
   <local:SomeTypeThatHasAEnumerableProperty x:Key="HolderOfEnumerable" />
</Grid.Resources>
...
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EnumerableProperty, Source={StaticResource HolderOfEnumerable}}" ....>
```

Comment: Can you give me some advise in how to achieve this with two diferent datasources (non StaticResource).